# Spring Boot @Scheduled with Different Profiles

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a class in a Spring Boot application (Spring Boot ver. 1.5.10) that uses the @Scheduled annotation on a method and I want to manage the value of the execution interval for this scheduler in my `application.yaml` file. I was able to find answers on how to do this using `fixedRateString = "${some.interval.value}"`. The problem is that I have multiple profiles in the same `application.yaml` file and Spring is always selecting the value in the default profile. This happens even when I specify a different active profile (I can see that the correct non-default profile is active in the startup logs).

Is there a way to get Spring to use the value from the active profile instead of the default profile? I've seen solutions that utilize multiple `application.yaml` files (e.g. `application-dev.yaml`, `application-prod.yaml`). But this seems really clunky, and I'd like to avoid this if at all possible because we have some properties that don't change between profiles and I don't want to duplicate the values for maintenance reasons. Below is an example of my setup.

application.yaml

```
scheduled:
  rateValue = 1000

---

spring:
  profile: prod

scheduled:
  rateValue = 2000
```

Service Class

```
public class foo {

    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${scheduled.rateValue}")
    public void bar() {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show some proof like logs because it is working for me

Answer (score 4):

We can create multi-profile `application.yml` files:

```
scheduled:
    rateValue = 1000
---
spring:
    profiles: development
scheduled:
    rateValue = 1500
---
spring:
    profiles: production
scheduled:
    rateValue = 2000
```

Values which don't change can be omitted from given profiles.

More information: [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-multi-profile-yaml)